# How do I write this such that its not a comment key => value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I write the following in an rspec test:

```
post :create, :post_id => @post.id, comment: {author: @comment.author, comment_text: @comment.comment_text}
```

I get back something like:

```
  {"comment"=>{"author"=>"", "comment_text"=>""},
 "post_id"=>"8",
 "controller"=>"api/v1/comments",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

Which is the `params` passed to the `create` action in the comments. The issue is `"comment" => {}` I don't want that. The reason being is the following:

```
  def comment_create_params
    params.permit(:author, :comment_text, :parent_id, :archived)
  end
```

It doesn't take a comment object, and currently when I post to the comment controller, it all works as intended a new comment is created and life is grand. So how do I write my `post` "statement" such that it doesn't create a "comment object" in the sense of `comment => {}`

The error I get in the test a response code of 422, because whats being passed too the controller is not what the controller is expecting so it assumes the required fields are blank, such as `author` and `comment_text`

Answer (score 1):

Just don't permit comment params. You can create different method for that. It will be like:

```
def post_create_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:author, :content)
end
```

Actually, you should require the entity:

```
def comment_create_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :comment_text, :parent_id, :archived)
end
```

Comment: Uh no. I have decided, for my own reasons to not "require" `:comment` so please stick to the question at hand.

Comment: Way to be rude to the one person trying to help you...